# Rowlex: A property node cannot contain more than one entity description

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rowlex

when using Rowlex OwlGrinder to generate an assembly from an OWL file the above error message is shown.
The offending piece of OWL/XML is for example:

```
<DisjointClasses>
      <Class URI="&foaf;Document"/>
      <Class URI="&foaf;Organization"/>
</DisjointClasses>
```

but the same error message is also thrown in the case of multiple superclasses - e.g.:

```
<SubClassOf>
    <Class URI="&foaf;Image"/>
    <Class URI="&wordnet;Document"/>
</SubClassOf>
```

I am perfectly willing to accomodate my ontologies to a certain extend to be compatible with OwlGrinder, but the above code is happily processed by for example Protege so I assume it is valid OWL. Do you have a suggestion how to approach the - quite vital - information of disjoint-classes/multi-inheritance?

Thank you a lot,
Hinnerk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm - sorry for this. Looks like the problem actually was the file format of that Ontology being OWL/XML. When using RDF/XML things worked fine.